# AngularJS routing and when back reset all

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I click on the button and AngularJS call routing for loading the details page. Why when I back to the home page (back button on browser) Select element on html lost value and list of people?

this is my code:

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Test</h2>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <select ng-options="people.id as people.name for people in peoples" ng-model="test">
        <option value="">Select People...</option>
        </select>

        <a href="#/details/{{people.id}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Details</a> 
  
    </div>
  </div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  
 $scope.peoples = [
     {id: '1', name: 'Jon'},
     {id: '2', name: 'Peter'}
   ];

  

 }
```

APP.JS:

```
 App.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider          
            .when('/details/:id', {
                templateUrl: configuration.appPartialPath + 'details.html',
                controller: 'DetailsCtrl'
            })

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Controllers in Angular are created on demand. When you leave a view managed by a controller it is destroyed along with its scope and a new one is created when entered the same view again. If you want to keep your scope data you will have to put it in somewhere else.

Since Angular services are singletons they can be use for that purpose. All you need to do is to inject such a service into your controller and bind it to a scope variable exposed to a view. Every time a new controller is created the same service with your data will be injected into it.

Comment: Give me some tutorial or examples? Thank's Daniel.